# Reading json files using custom schema in spark not returning results

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr

I'm new to emr/hdfs/hive/spark world. I have a collection of large json files (>50GB per file) that I am attempting to load so as to query specific keys. There is a standard layout for the json files but not all files contain all keys. I've created a custom schema that encompasses the entire standard and have created a dataframe using this schema. When I attempt to read/query json files only nulls are returned. I am attempting to POC loading the files within an EMR cluster using hive/spark. Is there a better way to process terabytes of json files?

To simplify the problem, say the complete standard is:
reporting_entity_name string
reporting_entity_type string
version string

File A will have reporting_entity_name and version but not reporting_entity_type.
File B will have reporting_entity_name and reporting_entity_type but not version.

The qry is:
scala> spark.sqlContext.sql("SELECT reporting_entity_name,reporting_entity_type,version FROM vw ").show()

I need File A to return:

+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|reporting_entity_name|reporting_entity_type|version|
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Mega Company Inc ...| null                | 1.3.1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+

and File B to return:

+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|reporting_entity_name|reporting_entity_type|version|
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| Mega Company Inc ...| Health Insurance ...|  null |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+

but what is returned from both files is:

+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|reporting_entity_name|reporting_entity_type|version|
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| null                | null                |  null |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------+

The actual standard json is more complex than the above example and can be found here:
https://github.com/CMSgov/price-transparency-guide/tree/master/schemas/in-network-rates#providers-object

Here is my custom schema:

```
`val schema = StructType(List(
StructField("reporting_entity_name", StringType), 
StructField("reporting_entity_type", StringType), 
StructField("plan_name", StringType), 
StructField("plan_id_type", StringType),  
StructField("plan_id", StringType), 
StructField("plan_market_type", StringType), 
StructField("in_network", ArrayType(StructType(List(
    StructField("negotiation_arrangement", StringType), 
    StructField("plan_name", StringType), 
    StructField("billing_code_type", StringType), 
    StructField("billing_code_type_version", StringType), 
    StructField("billing_code", StringType), 
    StructField("description", StringType), 
    StructField("negotiated_rates", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
        StructField("negotiated_prices", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("negotiated_type", StringType),
            StructField("negotiated_rate", StringType),
            StructField("expiration_date", StringType),
            StructField("service_code", ArrayType(StringType)),
            StructField("billing_class", StringType),
            StructField("billing_code_modifier", ArrayType(StringType)),
            StructField("additional_information", StringType)))), true),
        StructField("provider_groups", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("npi", ArrayType(StringType)),
            StructField("tin", StringType))))),
        StructField("provider_references", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("provider_group_id", StringType),   
            StructField("provider_groups", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
                StructField("npi", ArrayType(StringType)),
                StructField("tin", StringType))))),
                StructField("location", StringType))))))))),
    StructField("bundled_codes", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
        StructField("billing_code_type", StringType),
        StructField("billing_code_type_version", StringType),
        StructField("billing_code", StringType),
        StructField("description", StringType)))), true),
    StructField("covered_services", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
        StructField("billing_code_type", StringType),
        StructField("billing_code_type_version", StringType),
        StructField("billing_code", StringType),
        StructField("description", StringType)))), true),
        ))), true ),
StructField("provider_references",ArrayType(StructType(Array(
        StructField("provider_group_id",StringType),
        StructField("provider_groups",ArrayType(StructType(Array(
            StructField("npi",ArrayType(StringType),true),
            StructField("tin",StringType)))),true),
            StructField("location",StringType)))),true),
```

StructField("last_updated_on",StringType),
StructField("version",StringType)))`

A small sample file (of the above standard) can be found here:
https://webtpa-public-access.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/subfolder/2023-04_070_09B0_in-network-rates_01_of_122.json.gz

Comment: If the schema is wrong, then `null` output is expected. IMO, it's not possible to make one "master schema" for mismatching data.

Comment: Also, there is a different between `StructType(List` and `StructType(Array`. I think you should only use one. Scala `Array()` has no relation to Spark's `ArrayType`

Answer (score 0):

In the linked docs, in the table, it says values like `plan_name` are **not** required. Therefore, you need to add a third parameter of `True` for nullability of that field.

Repeat the same for all other non-required fields. Or make sure to set all required ones to False nullability.

---

Or, the better way -

There seems to be a JSON Schema file provided at

https://github.com/CMSgov/price-transparency-guide/blob/master/schemas/in-network-rates/in-network-rates.json

You can use `DataType.fromJson(fileContentsAsString)` to read that.

The Scala docs don't have a full example, but [PySpark does](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.fromJson).

So, you can then use that with `from_json(e: Column, schema: DataType)` function, or `spark.read.schema(dataType).json("path")`